# VB.Net Returning all lines from a text file that contain a specific string

Tags: vb.net, powershell, text, code-translation

I am new to programming and Stack Overflow so apologies if there is any info that I have missed/not provided, i am happy to make any adjustments to this post should they be required.

I am trying to write an application that looks at each line inside of a text file that contains a specified string and output each matching line to another text file. For example, if I search for all lines containing the string 'le' from:

```
apple
orange
lemon
banana
```

apple and lemon would be output to a separate file.

The code that I have will only return the first match and then exit the loop, without looking for other matches. Please see below:

```
  Using reader As New StreamReader(inputFilePath)
        While Not reader.EndOfStream
            Dim line As String = reader.ReadLine()
            If line.Contains(searchString) Then
                Dim outputFile As System.IO.StreamWriter
                outputFile = My.Computer.FileSystem.OpenTextFileWriter(outputFilePath, True)
                outputFile.WriteLine(line)
                outputFile.Close()
                Exit While
            End If
        End While
    End Using
```

Why is the code exiting the while loop even though the EndOfStream condition isn't met?

Based on the example above the results I get are:

```
apple
```

not:

```
apple
lemon
```

I understand that I am not using an append to add results consecutively however if this was the bulk of the problem, surely the results I would get would be:

```
lemon
```

as 'apple' would have been found but overwritten by the second result.

Please can anyone help, once again I am sorry for having to bother anyone, and I am especially sorry if the question is terribly worded or lacking info but I would be eternally grateful to anyone that can help. This is my first programming project and I would really like to make a success of it.

Incidentally the project was originally wrote as a powershell script, which works fine so if anyone who can help is struggling to decipher my issue the following code runs perfectly in PowerShell and gives the expected results.

```
$inputFile = Read-Host -Prompt 'Input File- Paste the filename, its 
extension and its path here. Eg- C:\input.log'
$outputFile = Read-Host -Prompt 'Output File- Type the filename its 
extension and its path here. Eg- C:\output.log'
$Pattern = Read-Host -Prompt 'Please paste/type the data to be searched.'

select-string -path $inputFile -Pattern $Pattern | select line | out-file 
$outputFile
```

Thanks Again.

Answer (score 2):

This is due to your `Exit While` line inside the loop. This exits the entire loop after your first match. If you just remove that line, then it should work.

Also, this is a bit of a tangent, but it would be better to open the output file once and then close it after the loop, instead of opening it and closing it on every iteration. (This will be less efficient if you have no matches, but a lot more efficient if you have multiple matches.) Something like the following should do the trick.

```
Using reader As New StreamReader(inputFilePath), writer As New StreamWriter(outputFilePath)
    While Not reader.EndOfStream
        Dim line As String = reader.ReadLine()
        If line.Contains(searchString) Then
            writer.WriteLine(line)
        End If
    End While
End Using
```

Caveats: I have done a lot of programming, but I've never used VB.net before, and the above code is untested, so please take this advice with a large grain of salt!

Comment: Well Thank you so much Mr Jack Taylor. You are a gentleman and a scholar.

Your code worked perfectly first time and thank you for pointing out that the stream needed to be opened and closed every time it would have looked through the loop.

Comment: Wrap it in using statements (StreamWriter) so objects get disposed as well.

Comment: @Zaggler I've updated my answer - does that look OK to you?

Comment: It's a small thing but you don't have to nest multiple `Using` blocks unless you want to put other code between two `Using` statements or two `End Using` statements. Otherwise, one `Using` statement can be used to create multiple objects, e.g. `Using reader As New StreamReader(inputFilePath), writer As New StreamWriter(outputFilePath) ... End Using`.

Answer (score 2):

While Jack Taylor is quite correct that a small change to your existing code will fix your immediate issue, you could also simplify your code in such a way that would make your original mistake impossible:

```
File.AppendAllLines(outputFilePath,
                    File.ReadLines(inputFilePath).
                         Where(Function(line) line.Contains(searchString)))
```